# Intercept global audio output in os x?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio

Has anyone come across a way to intercept (and modify) audio in OS X before it reaches the speakers? I realize I can build a driver and change the audio settings to output there, but what I would like to do is use the existing audio output and manipulate the stream before it reaches the chosen device, without the driver redirect trick. I'd also like to do the inverse and hook the microphone stream before it hits the rest of the pipeline.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Isn't this what applications like Jack or Audio Hijack do? If so, then it's obviously possible, as they undoubtedly exist.

Comment: They use a driver, as does boom -- im trying to avoid doing that

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of `CoreAudio` "drivers", kernel-level and user-space. From your question it isn't clear whether you want to avoid kernel-level drivers only or either type.

If you're willing to write a user-space driver, also known as a `HAL` plugin, that can be used to intercept system level audio output.

Take a look at Apple's examples [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013590-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)